# Laravel 5.8: Trying to get property 'created_at' of non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm using Laravel 5.8 to develop my project and in this project, I have a **OneToMany** relationship between `Member` Model & `Student` Model like this:

`Student.php`:

```
public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'std_mbr_id');
    }
```

`Member.php`:

```
public function student()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Student::class,'std_mbr_id');
    }
```

Then at the Controller, I added this:

```
public function index()
    {
        $student = new Student();
        $students = $student->searchStudents()->paginate(20);
        $custom = new Student();
        $customs = $custom->all();
        return view('admin.students.custom', compact('students','customs'));
    }
```

Now at the view I want to get `created_at` timestamp like this:

`$customs->find($student->mbr_id)->created_at`

But this will return this error:

**Trying to get property 'created_at' of non-object**

However when I do `dd($customs->find($student->mbr_id))`, I can properly get the timestamps:

[image]

So how to access the `created_at` timestamp in this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possibilities to throw `non-object errors.

First of all, make sure you have added the primary key in the `Student` Model.

`protected $primaryKey = 'std_id';`

Second is if you passed wrong `$student->mbr_id` in the `find()` method and directly access specific columns it will throw an error:

Please check in your blade file that record exist or not:

```
@if($customs->find($student->smbr_id))
    {{ $customs->find($student->smbr_id)->created_at }}
@endif
```

I hope you will understand and solved it.

Comment: Hey man, I just faced a new problem, would u mind plz help me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68601648/return-value-of-maatwebsite-excel-sheetmaparrayblerow-must-be-of-the-type-ar

Answer (score 0):

Why not leverage the Eloquent dynamic relationship property (See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) and use

```php
$student->member->created_at
```

Answer (score 0):

`find()` works with the primary key, which is std_id in this case. So to work with another field, you should do

```
$customs->where('std_mbr_id', $student->mbr_id)->first()->created_at
```