# Return value of Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet::mapArraybleRow() must be of the type array, null returned

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5.8, maatwebsite-excel

I am working with Laravel 5.8 with PHP 7.4 to develop my project, and in this project, I wanted to make an Excel file out of a table called `students`.

So here is what I did:

I typed `composer require maatwebsite/excel` at the Terminal and downloaded the package.

I added `\Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider::class,` in `providers` at `config/app.php`, and `'Excel' => \Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel::class,` as `aliases`.

Then I added this method to the Model `Student.php`:

```
public static function getCustom()
    {
        $records = DB::table('students')->select('mbr_id','mbr_mobile','mbr_post_code','mbr_address','mbr_name','mbr_family','mbr_national_code','mbr_mobile','province','city','degree','grade');
        return $records;
    }
```

And then made this new Export file:

```
php artisan make:export StudentExport --model=App\Member\Student
```

And this file holds this:

```
use App\Member\Student;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\withHeadings;

class StudentExport implements FromCollection, withHeadings
{
    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            'Name',
            'Family Name',
            'National Code',
            'Mobile Number',
            'Province',
            'City',
            'Degree'
            'Grade',
            'Registered at',

        ];
    }
    /**
    * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
    */
    public function collection()
    {
        return collect(Student::getCustom());
    }
}
```

And at the Controller, I have added these methods:

```
public function exportIntoExcel()
    {
        return Excel::download(new StudentExport, 'studentlist.xlsx');
    }

    public function exportIntoCSV()
    {
        return Excel::download(new StudentExport, 'studentlist.csv');
    }
```

And also these routes to `web.php`:

```
Route::get('export-excel','StudentAdminController@exportIntoExcel');
Route::get('export-csv','StudentAdminController@exportIntoCSV');
```

But when I try both of these routes, I get this as result:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError
> (E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR)
>
> Return value of Maatwebsite\Excel\Sheet::mapArraybleRow() must be of the type array, null returned

So what's going wrong here?

Comment: Hey! you have added space after grade column. Please check

Comment: @SNSharma Where?

Comment: Modal `Student.php`

Comment: @SNSharma Nice catch but didn't solve the problem

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your modal

```
public static function getCustom()
{
     $records = DB::table('students')->select('mbr_id','mbr_mobile','mbr_post_code','mbr_address','mbr_name','mbr_family','mbr_national_code','mbr_mobile','province','city','degree','grade')->get();
     return $records;
}
```

In your export file

```
return Student::getCustom();
```

Comment: Could u help me with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68526349/laravelexcel-interface-app-exports-formview-not-found

Answer (score 0):

You need to return an array or object from `getCustom` method

```
public static function getCustom()
{
    $records = DB::table('students')->select('mbr_id','mbr_mobile','mbr_post_code','mbr_address','mbr_name','mbr_family','mbr_national_code','mbr_mobile','province','city','degree','grade')->get();
    return $records;
}
```